# How to deal with checkbox?

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I've got a form with several checkboxes. You can add new form OR edit old one. This is where things get tricky.

If I submit form, PHP only gets values from CHECKED checkboxes. Now I update the value in database.

If I later update/edit the form and want to set checkbox UNCHECKED, it doesn't get the value and it doesn't update the value in database.

How to solve this issue? Please note that hidden input with same name is not an option because I've got several checkboxes with same names as like this: `name="name[]"`.

```
<?php
//Get value from dp - for editing
$feature_one = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'feature_one', true );
$feature_two = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'feature_two', true );
$feature_three = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'feature_three', true );
//Etc, 25 in total
?>


<input type="checkbox" name="feature[]" id="feature-one" value="feature_one" <?php if (in_array("3", $feature_one)) { echo 'checked'; } ?> />
<input type="checkbox" name="feature[]" id="feature-two" value="feature_two" <?php if (in_array("3", $feature_two)) { echo 'checked'; } ?> />
<input type="checkbox" name="feature[]" id="feature-three" value="feature_three" <?php if (in_array("3", $feature_three)) { echo 'checked'; } ?> />
<!-- 25 in total -->

<?php
//Add (or update if editing) values on submit
foreach( $_POST['feature'] as $feature ) {

    if( isset( $feature) && '' !== $feature ) {
        $n_feature = $feature;
        update_term_meta( $term_id, $n_feature , 1 );
    }
} ?>
```

Comment: Unless and until you paste your code. No one is going to help. **We are not here to guess your code.** We need code to examine the real problem.

Comment: guess what you can't do with unchecked checkboxes? ;-) *Unless...*

Comment: Unchecked checkboxes have no value, no state of being. *Namaste'*

Comment: Updated my code if you really need it but I though this question was more about general princible how to use checkbox in edit page.

Comment: if it's a *"general principle"* thing you're looking for, then your question would be too broad/unclear/primarily opinion-based.

Comment: Im sorry if I sounded like that but there must be a certain technique to use checkbox in editing content? This is driving me grazy, I've been looking  solution for two days now.

Comment: There are lot's and lot's of posts about the principal of checkboxes and even some that guide you on how to get the state, or lack thereof, of checkboxes.

Comment: what I suggest you use then, are ternary operators.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Could you give me a basic example based on my example?

Comment: The link that @JayBlanchard gave you above, contains an example and may just be a duplicate.

Comment: This is opinion so maybe not appropriate but it would be easier not using an array of checkboxes. Instead give each checkbox a unique name. Then it's trivial to check them on the backend. `$n_feature = isset($_POST['feature_one'] ) ? TRUE : FALSE;`  If TRUE or FALSE isn't appropriate then substitute whatever works for your situation.

Comment: @DFriend Thanks for your suggestion. I'll consider it. Only problem is that I've got like 24-25 of them. I also need to output them in front-end. Im not that sure it that's performance, speed wise but it's probably going to happen if I can't find a better solution.